# EXT4 for very large (>1GB) files : increase block size, use block clusters, or both?

Tags: ext4, large-files

I'd like to format a 12 TB HDD (not SSD) **with EXT4**, in order to store large video files (each file being at least 1 GiB in size).

I am working with an x86-64 (a.k.a. x64 or amd64) processor.

There's of course the `-T largefile4` option of `mkfs.ext4`, but are there other optimizations that can be done ?

In particular, I wonder :

- Should I increase block size to its max (64K, `-b 65536`) ?
- OR should I use [block clusters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ext4/overview.html#bigalloc), and  set cluster size to its max (256M, `-C 268 435 456`)
- OR should I do both ?

What would be the best parameters in terms of both disk space and performance optimization ?

Comment: Have you consider using `XFS` which is designed to handle well big files?

Comment: @RomeoNinov : Thanks. I'll have a look into it, but my question is specific to EXT4

Comment: Can we infer from the usage you mention that : No need for journaling ? Sequential reads in a vast majority ? No application frequently fsyncing ?

Comment: @MC68020 : yes to all question. Basically, it's to store a large video collection. Not even to watch them, it's more of a backup. Besides the use case, the goal of my question is also to better understand the -b and -C options of EXT4 (e.g., what are the uses cases of modifying block size and/or using block clusters with EXT4).

Comment: I'd do *none*. `largefile4` reduces the number of inodes and you may have funny issues later on.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov : that's the purpose of `largefile4`. No need to have lots of inodes if you only store large files (default is 1 inode per 16 KiB, `largefile4` is 1 inode per 4 MiB, more than enough if you store only very large files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very document you linked says (emphasis mine):

> At the moment, the default size of a block is 4KiB, which is a commonly supported page size on most MMU-capable hardware. This is fortunate, as **ext4 code is not prepared to handle the case where the block size exceeds the page size**.

Out of well-known processor architectures capable of running Linux, only ARM, Alpha AXP, Itanium or PowerPC have/had the capability of using page sizes beyond the usual 4 KiB.

Although AMD64/x86_64 processors can use hugepages, that is not quite the same thing - the basic system page size is still 4 KiB, hugepages just allow assigning them in larger bundles to improve memory management efficiency in large-memory systems. This does not change the fundamental "ext4 block size <= system memory page size" requirement.

With PowerPC or 64-bit ARM processors, the page size (the basic "block size" of system memory management) can be increased up to 64 KiB, which allows the ext4 filesystem to scale up its internal operations too. On AMD64/x86_64 that option is not available, so block clusters would be the only available way to reduce the space and work required for filesystem metadata.

I've used a system that had an ext4 filesystem extended to >10 TB range, and running a filesystem check on it was not a pleasant experience. Granted, that was an old system whose filesystems had been expanded and re-expanded without any careful tuning, to way outside the limits of the system's original designed capacity. (It was also a video server.)

But based on that, I would say that ext4 definitely needs specific tuning to successfully deal with tens-of-terabytes filesystems. Like Romeo Ninov in the comments, I would urge you to reconsider other filesystem types if possible: although ext4 *can* be used with much larger than 10 TB filesystems, I think low tens of terabytes is about the current limit of what is generally *practical* to do with it.

However, if you essentially write the contents of the filesystem once and then keep it read-only, you would almost never have to run a filesystem check on it, which will avoid one significant pain point.

Comment: I understood that differently: I thought 4K block size is the limit on i386 systems, and 64K on amd64 systems. According to `man mkfs.ext4` :
"note that the kernel is able to mount only filesystems with block-size smaller or equal to the system page size - 4k on x86 systems, up to 64k on ppc64 or aarch64 depending on kernel configuration"

Comment: aarch64 is 64-bit ARM processors, not amd64. ppc64 would be old Power Macs and IBM i-series systems. I have not heard about 64K page support on any amd64 processor.

Comment: Depending on the processor, amd64 (e.g., x86-64) supports 2 MiB and 1 GiB page sizes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)#Multiple_page_sizes). Debian's wiki shows how to check what is supported (https://wiki.debian.org/Hugepages#x86_64). I just checked on my laptop (Core i7-7700HQ), it seems to support both 2 MiB and 1 GiB.

Comment: I don't think hugepages are quite the same as the fundamental basic page size of the CPU's memory management unit... but feel free to try it. The document you linked was from 4.x series kernels, maybe the limit has been removed since then. Just make sure you have backups of anything important.

Comment: I agree, hugepages seems to be something quite different. I just read Debian's wiki till the end : after having enabled hugepages in the kernel, you still need to enable it in the applications that are going to use it (and that have to support it), like MySQL, Java, PostgreSQL, and so on (https://wiki.debian.org/Hugepages#Hugepage_enabled_applications). So yes, it seem that hugepages are not the same as the page size of the CPU's MMU.

Comment: Accepting this answer. But I think you should edit it and make 2 modifications : 1/ Add that there's no sign that "this limit has been removed" (`man mkfs.ext4` still states that "the kernel is able to mount only filesystems with block-size smaller or equal to the system page size - 4k on x86 systems". And 2/ add that x86 systems, even x86-64, support only 4K page sizes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64). That was the missing part for me, to better understand your answer (TBH at the beginning I didn't even know what a page size was). I myself edit my question to specify that I use amd64

Answer (score 2):

Ext4 can handle files up to 16TiB and filesystems up to 1PiB reasonably well, and is regularly used at these sizes in some of the largest parallel filesystems in the world (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lustre_(file_system) for details). There shouldn't be any issues with 1GiB files and a 12 TiB HDD.

I have a handful of 10 TiB drives in my home file server with ext4. The default mke2fs options that enable extents and other features should provide good performance.

As for the `largefile` option, that is reasonable if you *know* that the majority of files will be very large. However, the overall space savings is not huge and may not be worthwhile. I ended up using my media server for backups as well, and that created a ton of small files.

Comment: Thanks for your input. BTW I agree with you concerning the `largefile4` option, the saving isn't that important. But your post doesn't address any of my 2 questions : would increasing block size (`-b`, if doable) and/or using block clusters (`-C`) provide some improvements ? I agree that ext4 with default options is quite decent (I too host my home data on some 8-10TiB drives for several years now), I just wondered if `-b` and or `-C` options would provide some improvements. I guess I'll just have to try and see...

Comment: No, you cannot use over 4kB blocksize on x86 systems, only on ARM systems with 64KB page size. Even then, this is used rarely and is more likely to have bugs as a result. The larger chunks are also only useful if you only have large files. For a 12TB filesystem it isn't worthwhile.

Comment: As I've understood, Lustre acts as a "meta-filesystem" that allows the data and metadata to be distributed to multiple individual metadata target and object storage target devices, on multiple storage servers. Each object storage target device would be an individual ext4 or ZFS filesystem. So the question would be: what is the *recommended* size range of individual ext4 object storage targets, in various kinds of Lustre use cases (mostly-read? mostly-write? half-and-half?)? In what kind of cases would a ZFS object storage target be a better option?

Comment: @telcoM you are correct that Lustre aggregates multiple disk filesystems into a single parallel network filesystem. Typical Lustre systems deployed today have HDD OSTs around 600TB and NVMe OSTs around 60TB each. Larger is typically better due to declustered RAID rebuild, and ease of management with fewer OSTs.

Comment: @LustreOne Cool. It seems things have improved quite a bit since the ~15TB ext4 server I mentioned in my answer - although I readily admit that was probably a "pathological" case: very old OS version, old e2fsprogs, and a filesystem that started orders of magnitude smaller and was never properly adjusted for new size (because production).

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on TelcoM's answer.... if you want to use a block size other than 4Kb on x86[-64] then you will need to recompile the kernel. This used to be the only way to support large filesystems with 32 bit kernels. But then along came large file suppport and 64 bit inodes. And  nowadays (unless you are still running on 32-bit) you don't even need to tell mount/fstab that a filesystem uses 64-bits. But there's still a lot of out of date information on the internet (e.g. the CURRENT aws documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/volume_constraints.html).

The block clusters in ext4 provided a workaround for 32 bit inodes / 4k block size.

But not only is this no longer relevant - 32 bit inodes + 4K block sizes limited the total size of a block device to 16Tb and you've only got 12.

There are reasons for using different sized block (or block clusters). IIRC, both Oracle and MySQL use an 8k block size internally - and matching this on the filesystem gives a significant increase in throughput.

So....no you don't need to do anything clever (other than using GPT rather than MBR if partitioning).

Comment: Sorry, but I am confused. You start by saying that "to use a block size other than 4Kb on x86[-64] you will need to recompile the kernel". And you finish with "no you don't need to do anything clever". So, which one is it ? Do I need to recompile the kernel on a recent x86-64/amd64 in order to format an ext4 partition with 64K blocks (`-b 65536`) ?

Comment: You don't need to do anything to have a large filesystem or large files. You do need to do things if you want to use a different block size. Read it again.

Comment: There's nothing you can do to increase block size on x86-64, 4K is the max supported size. Read the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, the kernel only implements 4k on X86-64 - its never been something I've been concerned about because there's no need to change it to support larger volumes with 64 bit inode support. The suggestion that >10Tb is not fit for for production will come as something as a surprise to the MANY organizations (like where I work) that operate hundreds if not thousands of server with such storage.

Comment: Also block size (storage) and page size (memory) are different things - they just have to be aligned on most OS.

Comment: "that >10Tb is not fit for for production will come as a surprise" : I agree, I'm using EXT4 with default options for many years now with 8-14TB drives, never had a problem. I was just curious about the optimizations that can be done if you know that you'll only host large files. I'll try to do a benchmark w/wo block clusters, to see if there's a difference in terms of disk space and/or transfer speed.